# readthedocs build fails with `Sphinx version error`

Tags: python, continuous-integration, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

readthedocs started to throw an error `Sphinx version error` during build, although there were no changes to the readthedocs configuration and dependencies are all pinned.

Here's the [repository](https://github.com/dask/dask-image) and a specific [PR] https://github.com/dask/dask-image/pull/344 for which the doc build fails. Here's the [error message in the readthedocs build](https://readthedocs.org/projects/dask-image/builds/23503914/):

(shortened)

```
Running Sphinx v4.5.0
loading translations [en]... done
...
Sphinx version error:
The sphinxcontrib.applehelp extension used by this project needs at least Sphinx v5.0; it therefore cannot be built with this version.
```

HOWEVER, sphinx is already pinned to >5 in the repository, but version 4.5 seems to be installed during doc build.

The error looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77818509/readthedocs-sphinx-build-failing-due-to-version-error), however in my case there's no such misconfiguration and the fully pinned doc environment defined in `continuous_integration/environment-doc.yml` hasn't changed since the fails started.

What's interesting is that `cat continuous_integration/environment-doc.yml` on the [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/projects/dask-image/builds/23503914/) shows something different than `continuous_integration/environment-doc.yml` in the repository. Namely, there's a conda dependency sphinx added at the end, as if readthedocs added lines in the background.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77848565/407651

Comment: Thanks for the hint @mzjn, but here the problem is that sphinx should be using version >5, but somehow it's not

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77853415/2214933

Comment: Thanks @StevePiercy. But I do want sphinx >5 and have sphinx==5.3 pinned. And readthedocs seems to correctly install sphinx 5.3 (as reported by the mamba install command), but somehow ends up using sphinx 4.5 for build.

Comment: I don't think RTD knows about your pin in https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adask%2Fdask-image%20sphinx&type=code. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#sphinx

Comment: Thanks so much for following this up! In my understanding sphinx should find the pin in the last result of your search https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adask%2Fdask-image%20sphinx&type=code

Comment: I meant RTD should find the pin in `continuous_integration/environment-doc.yml`